# Receiving fine, but when I call the updateChat() method in the game it won't show up

Tags: java, sockets, methods, client-side, client-side-data

I know that the client side of my program is receiving fine because when I system.out.println(message); it shows the message in the cmd prompt.  The only problem is that when I call the method to update the chat on the game frame (in the JPanel), the message won't show up.  Heres a few snippets of code, see if you can tell my why it wont update.

Client method for receiving packets:

```
public void receivePackets(int packetID, String line, int colon) throws IOException{
switch(packetID) {
    case 0: //player sending a message
    String token = line.substring(colon+1);
    chatHandler.updateChat(message);
    System.out.println(message);//this prints out
    break;
    case 1: //player position update
    int comma = line.indexOf(",");
    int playerX = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(colon+1, comma));
    int playerY = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(comma+1));
    break;
}
}
```

ChatHandler method for sending chat:

```
public void updateChat(String next) {
allChat[4] = allChat[3];
allChat[3] = allChat[2];
allChat[2] = allChat[1];
allChat[1] = allChat[0];
allChat[0] = next;
     System.out.println(next);//this also prints out
}
```

Here is the catch.  I know nothing is wrong with the updateChat method because when I call it from within the ChatHandler class, it updates the chat on the JPanel.  It just for some reason won't update the chat when it is called from the Client class.  I have even tried using this method within the ChatHandler class:

```
public void receiveChat(String message) {
    updateChat(message);
}
```

I hope you can help me.  Honestly, this should be working because the println method works, but the update chat method isn't, but oh well, I don't care as long as there is a solution.

Comment: In which thread is the receivePackets() method (and thus the updateChat() method) called? In the event dispatch thread, or in a background thread?

Comment: In my game class it is constantly repainting, so that isn't the case.  receivePackets is called in a background Thread.  The problem isn't it receiving data, or the system.out.println wouldn't work either, it's something to do with the ChatHandler class not wanting to let the Client class call the updateChat method.  Just tried the updateChat method in the MainGame class and it worked.

Comment: My point is that it seems that either you're calling swing methods from a background thread, which is wrong, or you're accessing shared data (the allChat array) from two threads without any synchronization, which is also wrong.

Comment: Ill try syncronizing.  I'm new to sockets, just learned how to work with them yesterday because I wanted to make my game public.

Comment: It isn't synchronizing, at least I don't think it is.  I surrounded the contents of updateChat with synchronized(allChat){}.  Would that be the correct way of doing so?

Comment: No. If some state is shared between threads, all the accesses to this shared state must be synchronized. Not just some method. You should encapsulate this state in an object providing methods and handling the synchronization issues in a single place.

Comment: "I know that the client side of my program is receiving fine". So it *isn't* a 'Socket issue'.

Comment: Alright this is just plain weird.  I can call the updateChat method in the MainGame class normally.  BUT.  In the MainGame class, I tried setting a string equal to the string received in the Client class, called System.out.println() on the String in the MainGame class, and it printed fine.  Then I tried calling the updateChat method in the MainGame class on the string that held data from the client class and it didn't work....

Comment: Ok, it has to be synchronization, because I set a string equal to "hi" in MainGame and in the actionperformed method I made it constantly update chat to the String that equals "hi" and also made it System.out.prinln it constantly. Then in the client class I had it so that when it received something to set String hi in the MainGame class equal to it. I logged in and sent "hey. As soon as it received it, in the cmd prompt i saw: hi hey hi hey hi hey (except each word was on a new line, I cant hit enter in this).  So any suggestions for how to sync it would be fantastic, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving the message, then it is not a socket issue and more likely a repaint issue. Ensure you are setting the text on the JComponent responsible for displaying it. Then, if necessary force a repaint.

Comment: It isn't a repainting issue.  My MainGame class calls chatHandler.paintChat(); and actionPerformed calls repaint() every 25 millis.